# Multiplying matrices by block

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matrix

I need to multiply matrices of different shapes, M and N with a finite size of MxN.

I think an example will make it more clear:

A (shape: 4x4) =

```
0  3  0  0  
0  0  4  0  
0  0  0  3  
0  0  0  0
```

B (shape: 7x7) =

```
3  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  2  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  1  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  -1  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  -2  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  -3
```

As a result, I want a matrix of shape (4*7 x 4*7) which means (28 x 28) as follows:

```
0  3*B  0  0  
0  0  4*B  0  
0  0  0  3*B  
0  0  0  0
```

where B is still our matrix of shape (7x7) and the 0 represents a block of all zeroes measuring (7x7).

Maybe there is a function with numpy which can do that... but I can't find it.

(just for information, that's for Quantum mechanics)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the Kronecker product, [np.kron](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.kron.html), which is convenient to make block matrices like this:

```
>>> A = np.array([[1, 2], [0, 1]])
>>> B = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 3], [0,0,0]])
>>> np.kron(A,B)
array([[1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6],
       [0, 1, 3, 0, 2, 6],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```